# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'zlib' while it is included

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have included  "zlib": "^1.0.5" in the package.json under dependencies. And did npm install. But still having the same console error. Any idea of what might it be wrong?

The console error I'm getting:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'zlib' from 'mathml/app/MathML/MathMLRenderer.js'